# Is there a way to represent a record type in a way of let binding in sml?

Tags: functional-programming, record, sml

if I have a record like below:

```
type president = {name: String, age: int};
```

can I represent the same information by just using the `let` binding and something simple as `fun` or `fn`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use type aliases in a `let` just like any other declaration:

```
let
    type t = {name: string, age: int}
in
    some_expression
end
```

Comment: Can I achieve the same thing as `type` does while not using `type`?

Comment: @TracyJackson You mean can you create a type synonym without `type`? No, you can't.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

```
fun f (x : {name : string, age : int}) = ...#name x...#age x...
```

Or perhaps more succinctly with pattern matching:

```
fun f {name : string, age : int} = ...name...age...
```

Or do you mean something else?